# Conflict of interests

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[Varnish with Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75226/varnish-with-magento) is asking about using Magento + Varnish.

I help maintain [Nexcess_Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/) obviously backed up by Nexcess, a Magento partner. I don't want to self promote me or the company but give an actual answer to the question by sending the OP to the extension's GitHub repo. The module is free and maintained mostly by the community.

Is this in some way opposite to the Magento Stack Exchange rules?

Comment: see this: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/27/146

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a free extension. So sharing this extension as an answer is not a problem I guess. But it would be nice if you can add some general thoughts about OP's problem and need to explain how this extension can resolve that efficiently.

Otherwise the answer looks like a link only answer and can be treated as a promotion.

Comment: Agree, good call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about Magento SE but on the SO main-site, asking for a library is off-topic. So if the answer is a link to a Github page, most likely the question was off-topic already.

If however you give an answer and explain how Varnish and Magento (could) work together while the question was asked specifically (e.g. where are cookie-names of Magento documented and how do they affect caching with Varnish or what not) and then provide a link to source-code on Github that shows exemplary how you implemented that (and the code is well written ;)) I'd say there is no problem with that.

You already wrote that this is no self-promotion, so I don't cover self-promotion so far. It would be a no-go.

For me this is merely not about free or non-free, but that an answer is self-contained on the site so the idea of creating Q&A works in a stable manner. References to other websites should only be references, not the actual answer/content.

And don't self-promote. AFAIK for that extension, you should have enough knowledge to give good answers. Place that project on your about page and disclose that you're a developer of it.

And as you see a conflict of interest, do full disclosure in the answer so a user reading it has a better grasp on the context of your answer.